# Javascript var displays good in console, not in html

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, console.log

I'm actually learning Javascript at a developer school, we have a calculator to make with just html, css and javascript.

I'm almost done, except that I have a problem and can't find the solution.

I have this function

```js
function calcul(operateur){ // fonction du calcul et affichage du résultat
    var lcd = document.getElementById("lcd");
    switch (operateur){
        case "+" : 
            result = Number(n2) + Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break;
        case "-" : 
            result = Number(n2) - Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "/" : 
            result = Number(n2) / Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "*" : 
            result = Number(n2) * Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break;
    } // résultat affiché, remise à zéro des variables en cas de nouveau calcul par l'utilisateur
```

Very simple, it just makes a calculation from 2 vars then displays the result in a div in my html file.

My problem is : result is ok when displayed in console, the line right after is putting it in the innerHTML, and it always displays 0... :(
I have other functions to display values in the exact same innerHTML and it works almost perfectly fine, so I'm stuck after hours of trying to find why it doesn't work as intented :/

Full html, css and javascript pages (respectively named index.html, BSoverload.css and script.js) are visible in this Github page https://github.com/Mikerhinos/Calc , sorry comments are in french because I'm studying in France so professors are french too.

Thanks to the people who will try to help me :)

Comment: [You don't have a `break;` in the proper place](https://github.com/Mikerhinos/Calc/blob/master/script.js#L39) for your `=` case statement block, so it continues down into the `C` case statement

Comment: @trincot reset() is resetting n1, n2 and the operator var.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Damn, thanks it was that, I didn't see that I missed a break :/ Lost hours reading everything lol... How do I mark your answer as my solution and add rep ?
Thanks again ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier in that file you have

```
        case "=" : // si l'utilisateur demande le résultat de l'opération
            if ((operateur !== "") && (n1,n2 >= 0)){ // s'il y a bien une opération à faire, la transmettre à la fonction de calcul
                calcul(operateur);
            }
            else {
                break; // sinon ne pas tenir compte de la touche
            }
```

Which only breaks in the `else` statement, so falls into the case below, in turn setting it to 0

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calcul(operateur){ // fonction du calcul et affichage du résultat
    var lcd = document.getElementById("lcd");
    var n1= 1;
    var n2 = 2;
    switch (operateur){
        case "+" : 
            result = Number(n2) + Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
             break;
        case "-" : 
            result = Number(n2) - Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "/" : 
            result = Number(n2) / Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "*" : 
            result = Number(n2) * Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break;
    }
    }// résultat affiché, remise à zéro des variables en cas de nouveau calcul par l'utilisateur
```

```html
<p id="lcd"> </p>

<button onclick="calcul('+')">Try it</button>
```

```js
function calcul(operateur){ // fonction du calcul et affichage du résultat
    var lcd = document.getElementById("lcd");
    switch (operateur){
        case "+" : 
            result = Number(n2) + Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break;
        case "-" : 
            result = Number(n2) - Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "/" : 
            result = Number(n2) / Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break
        case "*" : 
            result = Number(n2) * Number(n1);
            console.log(result);
            lcd.innerHTML = result;
            reset();
            break;
    } // résultat affiché, remise à zéro des variables en cas de nouveau calcul par l'utilisateur
```